# How to convert number to comma separated string in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to convert price to standard comma separated string for a given country. For example if we do it for India 100000 should convert to 10,00,000, but for US it should convert to 1,000,000.

I have seen locale library in python. It can be done using that.

E.g:

```
>> import locale
>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')
>> locale.format("%.2f", 100028282.23, grouping=True)
```

It works.

But i just want to know whether can we do it in Django using localization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, localization can do that. Also take a look at [THOUSAND_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#thousand-separator), [NUMBER_GROUPING](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-NUMBER_GROUPING), [DECIMAL_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DECIMAL_SEPARATOR) and [USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR) settings.

Comment: Hi can you tell me how to implement them, the links you have given are  settings link thanks

Comment: @ParitoshSingh It should work out of the box, depending on `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting. You can set it dynamically, for example with [django-localeurl](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/)